# React frontend on netlify can't connect to database

Tags: heroku, mern, netlify, mongodb-atlas

I have deployed the Node, Express backend API part of my MERN app to Heroku and my MongoDB is running on MongoDB Atlas.

The React frontend when run on localhost connects to the backend on Heroku fine and can retrieve/edit data from MongoDB Atlas.

But when I tried to deploy the same React frontend app on Netlify, the React app works but it can't retrieve data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably because of the IP restrictions on Atlas. You have to allow any IP to connect to your database.